# Get parent for GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, attached-properties

Is there a way to get the parent (ListView) for a GridViewColumn?

I have tried with LogicalTreeHelper and VisualTreeHelper but no dice.

I can share a what-have-you-tried that is a bit funny, it works but ugly is not close to describing it:

```
public class Prototype
{
    [Test, RequiresSTA]
    public void HackGetParent()
    {
        var lw = new ListView();
        var view = new GridView();
        var gvc = new GridViewColumn();
        view.Columns.Add(gvc);
        lw.View = view;
        var ancestor = new Ancestor<ListView>();

        var binding = new Binding
        {
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ListView), 1),
            Converter = new GetAncestorConverter<ListView>(), // Use converter to hack out the parent
            ConverterParameter = ancestor // conveterparameter used to return the parent
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(gvc, GridViewColumn.WidthProperty, binding);

        lw.Items.Add(DateTime.Now); // think it cannot be empty for resolve to work
        ResolveBinding(lw);
        Assert.AreEqual(lw, ancestor.Instance);
    }

    private void ResolveBinding(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        element.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        element.Arrange(new Rect(element.DesiredSize));
        element.UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

```
public class GetAncestorConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ancestor = (Ancestor<T>)parameter;
        ancestor.Instance = (T)value;
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

```
public class Ancestor<T>
{
    public T Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is unfortunately hidden behind an internal property of the `DependencyObject` `InheritanceContext` so the only way to access it is via reflection. So if you are comfortable with that then this solution will work.

```
public class Prototype
{
    [Test, RequiresSTA]
    public void HackReflectionGetParent()
    {
        var lw = new ListView();
        var view = new GridView();
        var gvc = new GridViewColumn();
        view.Columns.Add(gvc);
        lw.View = view;

        var resolvedLw = gvc.GetParents().OfType<ListView>().FirstOrDefault();
        Assert.AreEqual(lw, resolvedLw);
    }
}

public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo InheritanceContextProp = typeof (DependencyObject).GetProperty("InheritanceContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetParents(this DependencyObject child)
    {
        while (child != null)
        {
            var parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parent == null)
            {
                if (child is FrameworkElement)
                {
                    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
                }
                if (parent == null && child is ContentElement)
                {
                    parent = ContentOperations.GetParent((ContentElement) child);
                }
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    parent = InheritanceContextProp.GetValue(child, null) as DependencyObject;
                }
            }
            child = parent;
            yield return parent;
        }
    }
}
```

There was [some discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wpf-disciples/hmGye6bGJCM) about this being made public back in 2009 and nothing has happened so I doubt it will be. That said the property is used extensively within the framework and is [Friend Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx) to other framework assemblies so I think it is a pretty safe bet it isn't going to change soon either.

Comment: Sweet extension method, think it will be useful, ty sir.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked 3 years ago but I've needed to do this a few times now, and I always keep coming across this answer, so I reckon other people with this issue will have the same problem.

I found an easy solution to this and similar problems provided you're willing to add a bit of code when the listview or gridview's parent object is instantiated.

Long story short: I leverage the .NET System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary functionality in that I create such a Dictionary(Of "object type I am notified of", "object type I need to retrieve"), e.g. Dictionary (Of GridViewColumn, ListView) - and load it at the instantiation of the parent object. If I then, say, get a GridViewColumn and I need to know what its "parent" listview is, I simply refer to this Dictionary to get it.

Seems to to the job for me :)

Comment: Sample code is usually good in an answer. I don't understand enough to upvote it as it is now.